# Sorting psql records by ordinal with single query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm trying to update some records in my psql database so that their "position" column is updated based on an array of integers. My action method looks something like this:

```rb
def sort
  # TODO: move to single query
  params[:order].each do |id, index|
      Topic.where({ id: id }).update_all(position: index.to_i)
  end
end
```

This runs a query for each record in `:order`. I'd like to combine them into one query, but the [method shown here](http://thepugautomatic.com/2008/11/rails-jquery-sortables/) seems to be mysql-only. I'm not familiar with psql enough to know if the same is accomplishable.

Comment: Have you read the comments to that blog? There's always a CASE statement to inline the mapping too.

Comment: I didn't ("don't read the comments" and all that). Will check it out. Thanks.